# Create Index from Two Fields Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python pandas and would definitely appreciate some tips.

I have the code below, which I am using to create a set of dummy variables from one field indexed by another field.  What I would like to do is create an index instead based on a combination of the ASSET_SUBS_END_DT field and another field called CSN.  Again, thanks for any advice.

Code:

```
df = data

df = df.set_index('ASSET_SUBS_END_DT')

Dummies=pd.get_dummies(df['EXPERTISE'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I misunderstanding or do you just want to set two indices? e.g.:

```
df = df.set_index(['ASSET_SUBS_END_DT','CSN'], inplace=True)`
```

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me on this.  I tried changing the index as you suggested, and now I'm getting an error: TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-9-fd25eeda48b6> in ,module.() ----> 1 Dummies=pd.get_dummies(df['EXPERTISE'])  TypeError: 'NoneType' Object has no attribute '___getitem__'

Comment: Have you already set up the CSN data as a column in the dataframe?  Do that first and then you can set it as an index.

Comment: I changed your suggestion slightly to: df = df.set_index(['ASSET_SUBS_END_DT','CSN']) and it seems to work.  I have a new issue though, I get multiple rows for each unique occurrence of ASSET_SUBS_END_DT and CSN.  For example 10/30/2008 and 5655008 for the same 1 value of dummy variable column.  Do you have a suggestion for how I could get one row for the combination of 10/30/2008 and 565008 with a 3 in the dummy variable column?